# How does OpenStack Floating IP assocation work underneath?

Tags: linux, networking, openstack, bridge, floating-ip

I created ~10 nodes DevStack installation to learn more about how OpenStack manages the networking. I created some VMS, and verified them on some host like following:

```
virsh # list
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 2     instance-0000001b              running
 3     instance-0000001f              running
 4     instance-00000024              running
 5     instance-0000002c              running
```

I have associated a floaring IP to instance id 2, I verified it by looking its openstack id and matching with output of virsh dumpxml 2. It has teh following floating IP: 172.16.6.12 and local ip: 10.4.128.11

I see it uses vnet0:

```
   <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='fa:16:3e:a1:f8:65'/>
      <source bridge='br100'/>
      <target dev='vnet0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <filterref filter='nova-instance-instance-0000001b-fa163ea1f865'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
```

Doing ifconfig vnet0, it shows no IP address:

```
vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:16:3e:a1:f8:65  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc16:3eff:fea1:f865/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:70 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:44216 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:7232 (7.2 KB)  TX bytes:29123311 (29.1 MB)
```

As I execute `ip addr`, I see the IP address is defined in the bridge, `br100`.

```
4: br100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether d8:50:e6:c3:22:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.4.128.13/20 brd 10.4.143.255 scope global br100
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 172.16.0.101/21 brd 172.16.7.255 scope global br100
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 172.16.6.12/32 scope global br100
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 172.16.6.19/32 scope global br100
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::80b6:99ff:fef7:dc16/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br100 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/ether fe:16:3e:a1:f8:65 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc16:3eff:fea1:f865/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

- 172.16.0.101/21 : The host IP
- 172.16.6.12/32: The VM Floating IP

However, where is the assocation that vnet0 --> 172.16.6.12 (floating IP) ? Why the traffic coming to 172.16.6.19 do not go to 172.16.6.12,

I looked for iptables rules, but there is nothing indicating vnet0 or the floating ip. How is this done? I see they are bridged with brctl, but there is no IP-MAC association I can see. It is not even in arp tables. I looked into iptables or listening ports if any forwarding is done is userspace, but it is not.

```
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br100       8000.d850e6c322ee   no      eth0
                                        vnet0
                                        vnet1
                                        vnet2
                                        vnet3
```

Comment: Is this using nova-network ? neutron?  If neutron, in what configuration?  any special drivers / hardware in play?  this stuff is HIGHLY configurable in openstack.

Comment: Well I guess devstack uses nova-network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found it. I forgot to look at iptables NAT rules, it uses to forward given floating ips to that veth devices.